# Shortening URL containing query strings

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, mysql, codeigniter

I'm using Codeigniter(PHP Framework) and I have URLs like `http://www.mysite.com/age/21/gender/female/name/jamie/city/boston/userid/1234`.

Is it possible to make the URL more SEO/user friendly? Like `http://www.mysite.com/1234-Jamie-Boston` and somehow still be able to pass the values found in the original URL strings like `age =>21` and `gender => female`?

Comment: Have you tried `GET` parameters? or [query string](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string)

Comment: I try not to use query strings as its against the design of the Codeigniter framework. I'm writing a search engine for a site and the URL is really long with lots of parameters in the segment based URLs `http://www.mysite.com/searchterm/funny/since/2011/sortby/ratings/shorterthan/3/page/5`

Comment: My apologies i didn't see the  codeigniter tag

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you could - use `mod_rewrite` to rewrite your new url from `http://www.mysite.com/1234-Jamie-Boston` to `http://www.mysite.com/user/1234`. In your user controller load from the db the one with id 1234 and set all his other properties

Or without the `mod_rewrite` - you could modify your `application/config/routes.php` file with an entry like:

```
$route['(\d+)-.*'] = "users/display_user/$1";
```

This way your SEO friendly urls will point to class Users, method display_users and you will get the id as parameter

Comment: +1 from me. I've used the routes.php approach, and left my .htaccess file alone. In that scenario I was able to treat all top-level sub directories differently from my "industries" pages - essentially, made it easy to write an abstract class for everything and a distinct class just for industries. btw - watch the order of your routes.

Answer (score 2):

The way that PHP works is that if you send 15 parameters to a function which only requires two, then PHP can more or less "swallow" the other arguments (they're still accessible, but they are less than optional). In your case, I would create a Users controller, perhaps with a display function which only takes one parameter, the user ID. That way, you can have `/users/display/1234/whatever/you/would/like/zodiac_sign/stop_sign/favorite_letter/favorite%20punctuation/...` Need I go on?

You can get around the need for a controller/method as part of your URL by using the $routes config file... In this case, I don't think `user/display` would really hurt SEO. I would not use mod_rewrite to do that simply because the architecture is already there in CodeIgniter.